# set DNS on ppp connection via systemd/dbus busctl

Tags: debian, systemd, dns, d-bus

Setup:

A debian jessie device connection via ppp to the internet

We use systemd-networking and no /etc/network/interface at all.

systemd-resolved is used for DNS.

Versions:

```
systemctl --version
systemd 230
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
armv7l GNU/Linux
kernel 4.4.14-v7+
```

(versions are the ones from jessie-backports)

This works fine for Ethernet + W-Lan, but fails for ppp.

Reason: the custom hook up scripts

0000usepeerdns
000resolvconf

are still writing to /etc/resolv.conf instead of connecting to the dbus server systemd-resolved provides.

so i am trying to get the PPP interface to have DNS resolution, which should be possible by calling SetLinkDNS via DBUS from what i did read (links at the end)

Get the interface ID (5 in our case)

```
ip l
..
5: ppp0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 700 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 3                                                         
link/ppp    
..
```

Read out current status of link interface 5

```
busctl introspect org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1/link/_35 |grep DNS 
.DNS                                property  a(iay)    0                 -
```

set DNS on Interface 5 with 1 IPV4 Address (google DNS as example)
(whats the explanation of the 3rd integer?)

```
busctl call org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1 org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager SetLinkDNS 'ia(iay)' 5 1 2 4 8 8 8 8
Link ppp0 is managed.
```

Read out values, still empty, so it failed to insert those value.

```
busctl introspect org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1/link/_35 |grep DNS 
.DNS                                property  a(iay)    0
```

So how do i debug this further to finally get it working?

falling back to /etc/network/interfaces or a "normal" /etc/resolv.conf is not an option.

Resources i used (plus a lot more but those are the relevant ones):

[systemd Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3225)

[freedesktop wiki network manager](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/systemd/resolved/)

[jonathanio VPN DNS issue tracker](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved/issues/12)

[VPN DNS change script from jonathanio](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved/master/update-systemd-resolved)

Comment: The third integer is the address family (IPv4 = AF_INET = 2, IPv6 = AF_INET6 = 10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue was happening because the network was already managed by systemd.

Disabling the management of systemd-resolved in the corresponding /etc/systemd/network/ file.

Reloading and restarting the deamons
`systemctl daemon-reload`
`systemctl restart systemd-resolved`
made the error message `Link ppp0 is managed` disappear.

I figured this out by reading more, asking in the freenode #systemd irc channel ,getting some pointer help there and reading the sourcecode.

Following sets the DNS on the interface 5 to the google DNS

```
busctl call org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1 org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager SetLinkDNS 'ia(iay)' 5 1 2 4 8 8 8 8
```

Comment: Note: this issue has been fixed in systemd 243 - now you can set DNS (via resolveconf or D-BUS) for interfaces managed by systemd-networkd as well.

Answer (score 1):

Old fixed bugs aside, *if* you happen to be using `systemd-resolved.service`, it is much easier today with `resolvectl`/`systemd-resolve` (On the system I'm testing on, these two are actually the same executable under different names). The `busctl` method still works well, though it is a little difficult to remember the syntax, especially for multiple DNS servers.

The examples below assume either `8.8.8.8` as the sole DNS server or `8.8.8.8` *with* `8.8.4.4`. The device being set is also being assumed to be `ppp0`.

## resolvectl

I find this to be the simplest today:

```
resolvectl dns ppp0 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

To view the status:

```
resolvectl status
```

## systemd-resolve

I haven't found how to assign *two* DNS server addresses using systemd-resolve, though I suspect it would be simple:

```
systemd-resolve --interface=ppp0 --set-dns=8.8.8.8
```

To view the status (note how the output is identical to `resolvectl`'s output):

```
systemd-resolve --status
```

## busctl

busctl with one DNS server:

```
busctl call org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1 org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager SetLinkDNS 'ia(iay)' $(ip link show dev tun0 | sed 's/:.*//') 1 2 4 8 8 8 8
```

The syntax of the fields after SetLinkDNS are "signature" `'ia(iay)'`, "device id" `7` (I had 7 this time, the id you get will differ), "number of DNS Servers" `1`, IPv4 addresses seem to require the next two parameters to be `2` and `4`, and then finally the four octets of the IP: `8 8 8 8`. Thus, for the two DNS servers, you would use:

```
busctl call org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1 org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager SetLinkDNS 'ia(iay)' $(ip link show dev tun0 | sed 's/:.*//') 2 2 4 8 8 8 8 2 4 8 8 4 4
```

You can get more information about the method/signature via:

```
busctl introspect org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1 org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager
```

To get the current DNS status:

```
busctl get-property org.freedesktop.resolve1 /org/freedesktop/resolve1 org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager DNS
```

---

There's probably a more direct way to get the device id from `/proc/net` ; but `ip link ... | sed ...` was the first that came to mind.